# Space of locally traceless tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, tensors

Let $X_{i_1,i_2,i_3,\ldots,i_N}$ be a  tensor with $N$ indices, where each index can take values $1,2,\ldots,m$, and $X$ takes values in $\mathbb{C}$, so the space of all such tensors is $\mathbb{C}^{m^N}$. We call  $X$ **locally traceless** if $$\sum_{i_{j}=1}^m\sum_{ i_{j+1}=1}^m \delta_{i_j,i_{j+1}}X_{i_1,\ldots,i_N}=0,~~~ \forall 1\leq j\leq N-1,\forall i_1,\dots,i_{j-1},i_{j+2},\dots,i_N \in \{1,\dots,m\}$$
where $\delta$ is Kronecker's delta symbol.

**What is the dimension of the space of all locally traceless tensors with $N$ indices?**

Comment: There are $m^N$ degrees of freedom in choosing $X$, and requiring $X$ to be locally traceless imposes $(N-1)\times m^{N-2}$ constraints, so one might expect the answer is $$m^N-(N-1)m^{N-2}.$$ This will be correct as long as the constraints are linearly independent of each other. I am almost certain that none of the constraints imply each other, but showing this rigorously might be a headache.

Comment: My advice would be try to prove @MikeEarnest's answer and see what happens. There are three possible outcomes, and you can then post a revision of your question explaining how far you got. Another suggestion is to try to cases where $m = 2$ and $N = 3$ or $N = $, by writing out the sums explicitly and see if there is any depenence in the equations.